# How do I provide a println! argument that is either an integer or string type?

Tags: string, rust, format

When I compile this code:

```
let n: u32 = 1;
println!("{} dice on the table", if n == 0 { "no more" } else { n });
```

The compiler gives me the error:

```
error[E0308]: if and else have incompatible types
 --> src/main.rs:3:69
  |
3 |     println!("{} dice on the table", if n == 0 { "no more" } else { n });
  |                                                  ---------          ^ expected `&str`, found `u32`
  |                                                  |
  |                                                  expected because of this
```

What is the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=67ff3b8de95da6ea2836c51b9ce97722), or if you wanted it [all in one expression](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6411225aed36de252c662254a94da1a7).

Comment: Thanks, your code snippets helped a lot. I found a Discord server where I can ask my noob questions.